# react-native-android-image-cropper: Not picking from camera but successfully picking image from gallery

Tags: android, react-native

I am using React native for my project and am using this package for taking pic from camera - react-native-android-image-cropper

https://github.com/zainozzaini/react-native-android-image-cropper

This is the code:

```
import ImageCropper from "react-native-android-image-cropper";

// More info on all the options is below in the README

let options = {
  guideLines:"on-touch",
  cropShape:"rectangle",
  title:'MY EXAMPLE',
  cropMenuCropButtonTitle:'Done'
 }
 
 /**
 * The first arg is the options object for customization (it can also be null or omitted for default options),
 * The second arg is the callback which sends object: response 
 */
 
  ImageCropper.selectImage(options,(response)=>{
      //error throwns with response.error
      console.log(response)

    });
```

The problem is I am getting nothing in `response` after clicking from camera - In the response I am getting `{}`.

However, it also, gives the option to select from gallery/ album - that is working fine. It is successfully populating the `response` when selecting image from gallery.
Only problem happens is when I click using phone's camera. I have given appropriate permissions in my Manifest file also for camera.

My `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
```

My `package.json`:

```
...
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-android-image-cropper": "^0.2.4",
...
```

How do I even debugging this ??